# How to update a cloned Magento?

Tags: ce-1.4.0.1, migration

I created a full clone of a Magento shop (all files, complete database) because I am moving to another server. After everything is tested on the new server, what do I need to update the new version? On the old server customers have created new orders and new customers are added. I am not sure if someone also changed some products but no new modules have been added.

Of course I need the database. But do I need files, too? `/media`maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When starting an upgrade on a copy of a server I would suggest halting all work on the original instance. At least as far as installing extensions, creating CMS pages, etc. goes.

After developing you might have changes in the database so that means you'll have to migrate data in a different way. But it might be with a try to just replace the data if you didn't make any settings changes.

A few options for that are export extensions like Magento's Dataflow extension but I always use a service called [cart2cart](http://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/). Basically because it proved to be reliable in the past and they offer good support.

After doing a migration of the orders, products and customers you should be good to go

Comment: I am sorry, I did not mean upgrade. It is just a move from one server to another with some minor file changes. It's all CE 1.4 for now. But your answer still might fit. I have a look at this. Thank you.

Comment: I've updated my answer but it stands as it is. Since you're gonna develop on the new shop transfering the old database again after you're done will probably not be an option :)

Comment: So if do not have any database changes because I only changed a PDF I am fine with a new DB copy and do not to take any file with me?

Comment: honestly if you've only changed a PDF, then definitely you can do this. Just truncate all the tables, maybe except for core_config_data and then export only the data from the old database. That should be enough, Oh and the `media` directory